# Emulating multiple screens

Tags: windows, display

I am looking for a software that could add virtual screens to my desktop. I need this for testing purposes

- for high / strange resolutions
- to get negative screen coordinates

So I want a new monitor to appear here:

[image: Monitor Setup in Windows]

I do *not* need [multiple desktops](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/94/software-for-emulating-multiple-desktops-on-windows).

The software must

- work on Windows 7 / 10 (x64)
- cost < 100 €
- support different screen resolutions, up to 4k (4096 x 2160 pixels)
- ideally support up to 9 screens so I can configure the maximum of 10 screens via the ordinary control panel

I don't necessarily need a way to see the contents updating in real time, but it should support creating a screenshot, e.g. with <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>.